# How to add printable text box annotation to a signed pdf using itext

Tags: pdf, digital-signature, itext7

I want add some printable annotation in signed PDF just like this

[image]

- The PDF is signed by digital signature
- The Textfield is forms and it will break the signature
- Normal annotation is unprintable or its content is unprintable such as stamp

Comment: A.The PDF is signed by digital signature
B.The Textfield is forms and it will break the signature
C.Normal annotation is unprintable or its content is unprintable such as stamp

Comment: This should not be a comment but an edit to your question.

Comment: What kind of signature is applied? (If it is a certification signature with "no changes allowed", you shouldn't be surprised that changes break it.)